# Excel: How is this graph even possible?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I made a line graph using two sets of data:

[image: http://s12.postimage.org/xd8772tjh/excel.png]

However, the blue line is totally out of place somehow and I have no idea why. I feel like I've checked everything. What could be going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following on from @fiso's answer, are you sure you have a scatter plot and not a *stacked* plot of some kind?

Answer (score 3):

For some reason the blue line in the graph is like the sum of both numbers, the blue and the pink.